# RxBluetoothkit call to retrievePeripherals fails second time

Tags: rx-swift, rxiosble

I'm using RxBluetoothKit 3.0.6 and have this code in a view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    DDLogDebug("DEviceChooser viewDidLoad")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
    //let timerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.polidea.rxbluetoothkit.timer")
    //scheduler = ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(queue: timerQueue)
    scheduler = MainScheduler.instance
    if let favs = EmaxProfile.getFavourites() {
        DDLogDebug("Got \(favs.count) favourites")
        var uuids: [UUID] = []
        for (s) in favs {
            if let uuid = UUID(uuidString: s) {
                uuids.append(uuid)
            }
        }
        DDLogDebug("Got \(uuids.count) uuids")
        if (!uuids.isEmpty) {
            let cbcm = CBCentralManager()
            let devs = cbcm.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: uuids)
            DDLogDebug("Direct call to CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals returned \(devs.count) entries")
            self.manager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: uuids)
                    .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                    .subscribe(onNext: {
                        DDLogDebug("Got \($0.count) devices from RXBluetoothKit")
                        //var list = self.devices[self.favourites]
                        for (dev) in $0 {
                            DDLogDebug("Adding device \(dev.name)")
                            let btDev = BTDevice(dev)
                            btDev.suitable = true
                            self.devices[self.favourites].append(btDev)
                        }
                        if (self.devices[self.favourites].isEmpty) {
                            self.startScanning()
                        } else {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }, onCompleted: {
                        DDLogDebug("Retrieve complete")
                    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
        } else {
            startScanning()
        }
    } else {
        startScanning()
    }
}
```

So in `viewDidLoad()` I'm retrieving a list of previously scanned devices, stored by their UUIDS, and trying to retrieve them without scanning. If I call the Core Bluetooth `retrievePeripherals` it works correctly every time. However using the Rx BluetoothManager call fails the second time - i.e. when I run the program, the first time this view is shown it works correctly. If I hit Back then immediately reopen the view, neither the `onNext:` closure nor the `onComplete:` closure executes. The log output is:

```
2017-01-12 19:55:13.824088 BlueMAX[559:216265] DEviceChooser viewDidLoad
2017-01-12 19:55:13.835820 BlueMAX[559:216297] Got 1 favourites
2017-01-12 19:55:13.836196 BlueMAX[559:216265] Got 1 uuids
2017-01-12 19:55:13.838832 BlueMAX[559:216265] Direct call to CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals returned 1 entries
2017-01-12 19:55:13.846427 BlueMAX[559:216265] Got 1 devices from RXBluetoothKit
2017-01-12 19:55:13.846927 BlueMAX[559:216312] Adding device Optional("DEV")
2017-01-12 19:55:13.849145 BlueMAX[559:216265] Retrieve complete
2017-01-12 19:55:13.909986 BlueMAX[559:216312] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
2017-01-12 19:55:21.515795 BlueMAX[559:216269] Saved 1 favourites, now exiting DeviceChooser
2017-01-12 19:55:22.054481 BlueMAX[559:216335] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
2017-01-12 19:55:24.650717 BlueMAX[559:216269] DEviceChooser viewDidLoad
2017-01-12 19:55:24.651417 BlueMAX[559:216269] Got 1 favourites
2017-01-12 19:55:24.651646 BlueMAX[559:216312] Got 1 uuids
2017-01-12 19:55:24.654465 BlueMAX[559:216335] Direct call to CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals returned 1 entries
2017-01-12 19:55:24.679889 BlueMAX[559:216269] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid
```

I'm not sure if the "XPC connection invalid" messages are connected with this or not.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could you tell me whether `self.manager` is injected from the outside, or maybe recreated in the init of VC?
And exactly how it is created?

What is `RxBluetoothKit` doing under the hood is simply calling the same method as you in the example above and mapping it to the `Observable` sequence.
Could you jump to the source code and debugger and see whether this line:

`return self.centralManager.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: identifiers)`

is called every time?

And maybe for convenience - please report this as an issue for Github, since it may require to take a while to reproduce the issue.
Thanks,